Права на запуск файла
В домашней папке пользователя A создал файл s.sh
Права 775. Пользователь A группа A
Создал пользователя B и добавил в группу A.
Почему требуется вводить пароль, когда пользователь B заходит в папку пользователя A и пытается выполнить команду:
bash s.sh

Для файла же установлено правило 7 для группы. Почему нельзя пользователю B выполнить скрипт без ввода пароля?
UPD:
Даже это не помогло:
sudo visudo
%A ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/path_to_file/s.sh


Почему вы решили, что требуется вводить пароль?

@andreymal я зашел через пользователя B и попытался выполнить эту команду и он потребовал пароль =(

Это может означать лишь то, что вы внутри s.sh понаписали какие-то команды, которые требуют пароль, и права на файл тут ни при чём

@andreymal, спасибо! Я думал что если в скрипте s.sh указать "-S <<< $PASS_ROOT sudo ....", то можно будет выполнить из под рута команду пользователю без рута. Но по ходу так нельзя.

NOPASSWD отработает только в команде вида sudo s.sh (и при этом владельцем файла и всех родительских каталогов должен быть root, чтобы другие пользователи не могли понаписать произвольные команды и получить полный root-доступ к компьютеру, то есть для безопасности такой скрипт будет логичнее поместить в что-то вроде /usr/local/bin/s.sh)

Кстати, чтобы скрипт искался именно в текущем пути его ещё нужно указать в PATH, по дефолту в линуксе обычно этого не происходит, в отличие от винды. Так что я бы ещё проверил, запускается ли при этом ./s.sh, или s.sh по какому-то другому вообще пути. В общем, лучше всегда указывать путь при запуске, хотя бы относительный.
